# Powershell: Error while replacing the sub-string in a file

Tags: powershell, replace, substring, powershell-3.0

I am trying to replace some of the sub-strings with some values across multiple files. I have written this code to do so.

```
$dirPath = 'C:\repos\sync_cpc_cva\ExpressV2\Parameters\AG08\KeyVault'
$ConfigPath = 'C:\repos\sync_cpc_cva\config.json'

$lookupTable = @{}
(Get-Content -Raw -Path $configPath | ConvertFrom-Json).psobject.properties | Foreach { $lookupTable[$_.Name] = $_.Value }

Get-ChildItem -Path $dirPath -Recurse -Filter *.json | 
Foreach-Object {
    
    Get-Content $_.FullName | ForEach-Object {
        $line = $_
        
        $lookupTable.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
            
            if($line -match $_.Key) {
                
                $line = $line -replace $_.Key, $_.Value
                
            }
        }
        $line
    } | Set-Content -Path $_.FullName
}
```

If I print the content, it has replaced all the values correctly, however, it is unable to set the contents into the same file. And I am getting following error while running the code :

```
Set-Content : The process cannot access the file
'C:\repos\sync_cpc_cva\ExpressV2\Parameters\AG08\KeyVault\KeyVault.USNat.json' because it is being used by another process.
At C:\repos\sync_cpc_cva\filltest.ps1:22 char:9
+     } | Set-Content -Path $_.FullName
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-Content], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetContentCommand
```

Any idea how can I replace the sub-strings in the same file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several inner foreach-object loops, so you modify the $_ operator while being used. I dont think this can work. Revolve it like this:

```
$lookupTable = @{}
(Get-Content -Raw -Path $configPath | ConvertFrom-Json).psobject.properties | Foreach { $lookupTable[$_.Name] = $_.Value }

$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $dirPath -Recurse -Filter *.json

foreach ($file in $files) {
    $content = Get-Content $file.FullName
    for($i=0;$i -lt $content.length; $i++) {
        $lookupTable.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
            $content[$i] = $content[$i] -replace $_.Key, $_.Value
        }

    }
    $content | Set-Content $file.FullName

}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. However, while pushing the changes to the git, getting this error:
Binary files a/ExpressV2/Parameters/AG08/KeyVault/KeyVault.USNat.json and b/ExpressV2/Parameters/AG08/KeyVault/KeyVault.USNat.json differ

Comment: this is probably due to the fact, we are creating a new file with the same name. Hence, both of them have different checksum. Therfore, git is unable to push the changes. Any idea how we can make changes in the same file?

Comment: Instead of Out-File, we can use Set-Content. We won't get any issue afterwards.